# Update every selected row

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgresql, let's say users:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  username character varying(24) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  timestamp_created timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
  new boolean DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL
);
```

With the following query, I select all users

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

What I want to achieve is the following: when a row is selected, the value of 'new' should be updated from false to true.

There is no BEFORE/AFTER SELECT in postgresql trigger functions, is there something similar?

**Edit:** I'm using NodeJS. Currently, I store all the user ID's of the returned rows in an array and do this query:

```
UPDATE users SET new = true WHERE user_id = ANY($1);
```

$1 is placeholder for the user ID's array.

Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: save the last update day date in a table and then update all rows, since that day/hour

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What happens if the select is done but something crashes directly after? Do you still want the rows marked as new again? It sounds like a very brittle architecture to me. I'm really curious what function you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat complicated way could be

```
WITH new_users AS (
   UPDATE users SET new = TRUE
   WHERE NOT new RETURNING /* all columns except "new" */
)
 SELECT /* all columns except "new" */
 FROM new_users
UNION
 SELECT /* all columns except "new" */
 FROM users;
```

The `UNION` will eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a SELECT, but you can do:

```
UPDATE users SET new=true WHERE new=false RETURNING *
```

This will return all users that had new=false and also update the table to set new=true in these rows.

Comment: That will not return users where `new` is FALSE.